# How to roundup a number to the closest ten?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Probably the title is not very suggestive.

Let me explain you with an example. I have:

```
12345.6 
2345.1
12345.00000001
```

I want those numbers to be roundup to `12350`.
How can I do this?

If possible, I would rather use formulas instead of VBA.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, don't forget to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If any of the answer fits your need, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the best answer.

Comment: Besides, for this kind of question (i.e. Excel formulas and no VBA), you could ask next time on http://superuser.com

Comment: I'm sorry, but I wans't correct in my question: I want 12340.0001 to be modified in 12350. :)

Answer (score 26):

You could also use `CEILING` which rounds up to an integer or desired multiple of significance

ie
`=CEILING(A1,10)`
rounds up to a multiple of 10

`12340.0001` will become `12350`

Answer (score 25):

Use `ROUND` but with `num_digits` = -1

```
=ROUND(A1,-1)
```

Also applies to `ROUNDUP` and `ROUNDDOWN`

From Excel help:

- If num_digits is greater than 0 (zero), then number is rounded to the specified number of decimal places.
- If num_digits is 0, then number is rounded to the nearest integer.
- If num_digits is less than 0, then number is rounded to the left of the decimal point.

**EDIT:**
To get the numbers to always round up use `=ROUNDUP(A1,-1)`

Comment: nice. I didn't know you could use negative numbers

Comment: Upvoted this answer because I wanted to use rounddown().

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `MROUND(<reference cell>, <round to multiple of digit needed>)`.

Example:

1. For a value `A1 = 21` round to multiple of 10 it would be written as
   `=MROUND(A1,10)`
   for which Result = 20
2. For a value `Z4 = 55.1` round to multiple of 10 it would be written as
   `=MROUND(Z4,10)`
   for which Result = 60

Answer (score 1):

the second argument in ROUNDUP, eg =ROUNDUP(12345.6789,3) refers to the negative of the base-10 column with that power of 10, that you want rounded up. eg 1000 = 10^3, so to round up to the next highest 1000, use ,-3)

```
=ROUNDUP(12345.6789,-4) = 20,000
=ROUNDUP(12345.6789,-3) = 13,000
=ROUNDUP(12345.6789,-2) = 12,400
=ROUNDUP(12345.6789,-1) = 12,350
=ROUNDUP(12345.6789,0) = 12,346
=ROUNDUP(12345.6789,1) = 12,345.7
=ROUNDUP(12345.6789,2) = 12,345.68
=ROUNDUP(12345.6789,3) = 12,345.679
```

So, to answer your question:
if your value is in A1, use
    =ROUNDUP(A1,-1)