# Excel: How to roundup a number to the closest ten2?

Tags: excel, formulas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel: How to roundup a number to the closest ten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587474/excel-how-to-roundup-a-number-to-the-closest-ten)

I made this question a few hours ago, but I wasn't very specific:

[How to roundup a number to the closest ten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587474/excel-how-to-roundup-a-number-to-the-closest-ten)

Probably the title is not very suggestive. Let me explain you with an
example. I have:

> ```
> 12345.6 
> 2345.1
> 12345.00000001
> ```

I want those numbers to be roundup to 12350. How can I do this? If
possible, I would rather use formulas instead of VBA.

This is the original question, but at the same time, I want the same result for: 
 `12340.0001` to be modified in `12350`. Somehow I don't know if this is still a round operation. :)

I'm sorry for duplicating the question, but posting a comment at the first question, didn't draw enough attention. :)

Comment: Is it correct that you would you like 12344 rounded down to 12340?

Comment: See my post in your original question that addresses your question

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 10, round with the regular function (Round x,0) and multiply by 10 again...

```
=(ROUND(E7/10;0)*10)
```