# Excel Formula multiples of 6

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have no idea how to do it in excel:

if A1 / 6 rest != 0, round A1 for next multiple of 6.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8590323/641067

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what the CEILING function does.

```
=CEILING(A1, 6)
```

This will round up A1 to the next multiple of 6.